# Decimal.Parse strange behavior on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox

In a MVC project, I have a variable set in the web.Config of my project like this:

[image]

Then in my code, I get that variable and parse it as decimal:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, this works fine, the problem is that when I run my code on Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, I have diferent results:

[image]

[image]

I dont undestand why that happens, as not happen in all machines that run the web on Chrome, all I can think is that it seems to be something on the browser config but its a standard instalation, nothing different.

Anyone can point me in the right direction? Or has an idea of what can be causing this behavior?

**UPDATE:**

Code in text (I don't know why, but ok)

**For easy-debugging I have this:**

```
    public static decimal ServiceFee
    {
        get
        {
            var webConfigVar = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceFee"];
            decimal webConfigVarDecimal = decimal.Parse(webConfigVar ?? "0");
            return webConfigVarDecimal;
        }
    }
```

**Normally, is like this**

```
    public static decimal ServiceFee
    {
        get
        {
            return decimal.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceFee"] ?? "0");
        }
    }
```

**And the Web.Config**

```
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ServiceFee" value="0.024" />
    </appSettings>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I know that the code run on the server, but the only difference is the Browser, and its always with those browsers on a few machines.

***No matter if the server is running local or on production***

Comment: Post your code as **text**

Comment: Also, C# code runs on the server; shouldn't matter what the browser is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Decimal.Parse` uses the `CultureInfo` of the current request request-handling thread, which ASP.NET can (though not by default) set according to the browser's `Accept` header - so that browsers set to French or German will use their formatting rules (where comma `','` is the radix place, not a dot `'.'`). This is probably what's happening: your Chrome browser is set to use a different culture.

The fix is to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when calling any `Parse` or `ToString` method if it is interacting with human-readable text (e.g. when loading a config file).

This is why static analysis is important (the "Analyze" menu in Visual Studio) - it can point out these bugs.

(My own personal opinion is that the `Parse` method should be removed from .NET and replaced with explicit `ParseFormatted(IFormatProvider, String)` and `ParseInvariant(String)` - but that's just me :)

I note that is inefficient to always call `Parse` in your property-getter. You should just cache it statically (using the new C# 6.0 read-only property syntax):

```
using System.Globalization;

public static decimal ServiceFee { get; } =
        Decimal.Parse(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceFee"] ?? "0",
            NumberStyles.Number,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        );
```

If you do this frequently you might want a reusable method:

```
public static Decimal GetAppSettingDecimal(String name) {

    String textualValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ name ];
    Decimal ret;
    return Decimal.TryParse( textualValue, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ret ) ? ret : 0;
}

public static Decimal ServiceFee { get; } = GetAppSettingDecimal("ServiceFee");
```

Comment: Perfect man!! Just perfect. I will consider the suggestion. Thanks man.