# Browser adds zeroes when posting in NopCommerce

Tags: localization, nopcommerce

When updating prices in NopCommerce Product edit, the zeroes behind the dot is added to the number.

e.g. 440.0000 becomes 4400000

The prices is stored in a decimal type. The language used on the client machine is Danish, which normally uses ',' as decimal separator. In the Edit webpage dot '.' is used as decimal separator and it will not accept ','. By googling around I have seen that other Danes has had the same problem.

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772470/decimal-parse-strange-behavior-on-chrome-and-firefox) could identify the problem and a maybe offer a solution. Can anyone tell me how to implement it in NopCommerce?

It is not an option to make any change in the NopCommerce source code, despite it's "open source", because I am trying to fix a legacy system.

The problem occurs in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Did you upload the Danes language pack at your nopcommerce?

Comment: @sina_Islam yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer just to close the question. Thanks to Raphael for his answer.

The only way to solve the problem is to set working culture and make a recompile, which as written in the question is not an option. Because I don't know if there are any custom changes in the legacy compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of nopCommerce you use have a look at

**Global.asax.cs - SetWorkingCulture()**

```
if (webHelper.GetThisPageUrl(false).StartsWith(string.Format("{0}admin", webHelper.GetStoreLocation()),
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    //admin area


    //always set culture to 'en-US'
    //we set culture of admin area to 'en-US' because current implementation of Telerik grid 
    //doesn't work well in other cultures
    //e.g., editing decimal value in russian culture
    CommonHelper.SetTelerikCulture();
}
```

**ComonHelper.cs - SetTelerikCulture()**

```
public static void SetTelerikCulture()
{
    //little hack here
    //always set culture to 'en-US' (Kendo UI has a bug related to editing decimal values in other cultures). Like currently it's done for admin area in Global.asax.cs

    var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```

The above code blocks represent nopCommerce 3.90.

> It is not an option to make any change in the NopCommerce source code, despite it's "open source", because I am trying to fix a legacy system.

Since you do not want to change the nopCommerce source code, you have no choice but to use nop Admin using en-US culture.

**Edit**

One thing you could try is adding one of the culture scripts provided by telerik. See `~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/cultures/...`

Although this requires a minor change on a view (source code)